# spark dataframe insert to hbase error

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with this schema :

```
 |-- Name1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- App: string (nullable = true)
...
 |-- Duration: float (nullable = false)
```

I want to insert it to hbase table. i used many [references](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_sparksql_dataframes) .
I define catalog:

```
def catalog = s"""{
       |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"otarie"},
       |"rowkey":"key",
       |"columns":{
         |"col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
         |"col1":{"cf":"cf1", "col":"Name1", "type":"boolean"},
         |"col2":{"cf":"cf2", "col":"Name2", "type":"double"},
         |"col3":{"cf":"cf3", "col":"App", "type":"float"},
            ........
         |"co27":{"cf":"cf27", "col":"Duration", "type":"string"}
       |}
     |}""".stripMargin
```

and than i tryed to write my dataframe:

```
Append_Ot.write.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5")).format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark ").save()
```

i'm using spark-shell and i got this error:

```
 <console>:155: error: not found: value HBaseTableCatalog
```